# <a href> appends link to end of current url

Tags: html, .htaccess

When I upload an HTML file to my website with `<a href="">` tags, the link appends the URL in the link to the end of the current URL.

For example, if my website was `example.com` and the index.html file was placed in `example.com/test` and the link was `google.com` then the link would go to `example.com/test/google.com`.

How do I make it so the link goes to `google.com`?

Comment: Where's your code? Does your href contain the complete absolute URL?

Comment: Show us *your actual code*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should really learn about absolute and relative paths. What you're using is a relative path.

This is an absolute path on your server:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png">
```

This is an url with http protocol - opens Google.com

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

This is an url without explicit protocol, it will turn into http or https based on what your page uses:

```
<a href="//google.com">Google</a>
```

Use one of those for what you need (typically the http one).

Answer (score 2):

This is what the code should look like for linking to Google:

```
<a href="http://google.com" title="Google">Google</a>
```

Make sure that your HREF contains the complete URL if you are linking to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below in you index.html file in angular to override this behavior.

`<base href="/">`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).